# Formula for confidence intervals for small samples and unknown population standard deviation

Tags: confidence-interval

I have consulted two texts on how to calculate to calculate confidence intervals when N is small and the population standard deviation is unknown. There are some differences in the formulas they give and the end result varies depending on which text I follow (although not by a large amount).
Text one says:

1. Calculate the mean
2. Calculate the standard deviation
   using the formula: s= √ ((∑ X(squared)/N)–X-bar)
3. Calculate the standard error of the mean using the formula: s/√ N-1
4. Determine the value of T from the t-table
5. Obtain the margin of error by multiplying the standard error of
   the mean by multiplying it by the value obtained in step 4.
6. Add and subtract this product from the sample mean to obtain the C.I.

Steps, 1,4,5& 6 are exactly the same in the second text. However it gives different formulas for steps 2 & 3.
It says:

1. Calculate the standard deviation using the formula: s= √ ((∑ X(squared) /N-1) –X-bar). The difference is that they reduce N by one.
2. Calculate the standard error of the mean using the formula: s/√ N  The difference is that N is not reduced by 1.

Can anyone explain why the different formulas are used and why?

Thanks. Anne S

Comment: Can you tell us which two texts gave you these sets of instructions? I'd be very curious to know.

Comment: Chris, Yes, One is from Fox & Levin  and the other is from Haan. Can you assist?

Comment: Is Fox and Levin "Elementary Statistics in Social Research" and is Haan "Practical Statistics for Business" and is the first set of instructions from the first text and the other from the second? I will post an answer momentarily.

Comment: @Chris Yes you have the correct Fox and Levin. The Haan is: An Introduction to Statistics. I struggle with writing the formula for the standard deviation on a website. I don't know how to use the correct symbols so I had to write it in words. Hope it is still clear. I am looking forward to your response.

Comment: This site uses a system called $\LaTeX$ to display formulas if you're interested you can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) knowing some can help you get the help you need. [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) is an editor program that can help you create the formatting.

Comment: Both your formulas for $s$ are wrong; the part with "$-$X-bar" should have the $\bar{X}$ squared.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some good notes on standard deviation and the standard error of the mean [here](http://www.cms.murdoch.edu.au/areas/maths/statsnotes/samplestats/stdevmore.html).

The Wackerly et al text computes small sample confidence intervals in section 8.8 (page 430) you can see their formula [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZvPKTemPsY4C&lpg=PP1&dq=wackerly&pg=PA430#v=snippet&q=Small-Sample%20confidence%20intervals&f=false).

Confidence interval: $\bar{Y} \pm t_{\alpha/2} * \frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$

Where $\bar{y}$ = $\frac{1}{n}$$\sum{\textstyle y_{i}}$ (the sample mean)

and $S = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(y_{i}-\bar{y})^2}$ (the sample standard deviation)

t$_{\alpha/2}$ is the critical value for a given value of $\alpha$ (e.g., .1, .05, etc.) and has n-1 degrees of freedom, where n is the sample size, that you'd find in a [table](http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/distribution-tables/#t).

Now if your sample is a large proportion of a known finite population size there is something called a [population correction factor](http://www.childrensmercy.org/stats/size/population.asp), but for basic needs you probably don't have to worry about this.

Comment: @Chris, Thanks for your reply but I don't understand. Can you comment on the formulas I posted?

Comment: What is it you do not understand exactly? From what you've posted I would say the second set of instructions are the ones I would recommend, but the way you wrote the expressions is unusual. such as s= √ ((∑ X(squared) /N-1) –X-bar) seems like you meant squaring the observation value and dividing it by n - 1. Instead of sum the differences between the quantity of the observation value minus the mean end quantity squared divided by n-1. So assuming what you typed was meant to be that formula then yes that second set of instructions is what you want. If its not what you meant please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I meant I do not follow the formulas from Wackerly et al. By  s= √ ((∑ X(squared) /N-1) –X-bar) I meant square all observations and then sum them, then divide this by N-1, and then subtract the mean(squared).

Comment: Can you explain why Fox and Levin subtract 1 from N in the formula for standard error of the mean and Hann does not and why Haan subtracts 1 from N in the formula for the standard deviation and does not subtract 1 from N in the formula for standard error of the mean. I read the notes from Murdoch. What I think I get from these is if you subtract 1 from N in the formula for standard deviation then you do not need to do this in later formulas. Is this correct?  Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Okay so the S in Fox and Levin is the standard deviation of the sample. The one used in Haan is the sample standard deviation which is an estimate of the population's standard deviation. Yes like you suspect the difference in the instructions is to create an unbiased confidence interval given their two different starting points for the standard deviations.

Comment: @Chris. thanks that helps a lot. The end results are slightly different. Can I clarify that you think the steps in Haan are more correct?

Comment: How different of results are you getting? Different enough to suggest a different conclusion? Yes I would follow Haan's instructions.

Comment: The differences are not large. Using Fox and Levin the CI is 4 plus /minus 1.24  while with Haan the CI is 4 plus/minus 1.2

Comment: For a small sample that isn't much of a difference. In a large sample that could be. Notice though that the Fox and Levin CI creates a more conservative (e.g. wider) interval and that the Haan CI is contained inside of it. If you want to give me the data you used to compute this I can compare to see which CI results SAS or R would say is more correct.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Yes I noticed that. So the difference would be larger the larger the sample? Thanks for your offer. The data is: 3 1 7 7 4 6 4 4 3 0 5 5 2 2 7

Comment: Computing a 95% CI in SAS using proc means I get [2.7795, 5.2205] If I were rounding to one decimal place this would be [2.8, 5.2] which is more similar to the Haan calculation of 1.2 than it is to the Fox and Levin 1.24. So I would say stick with Haan.

Comment: @Chris, thanks so much for all your detailed feedback. I find it intriguing that there are little differences between texts and different software packages even for a simple procedure like this. We have SPSS at school not SAS do you know how you would do this on SPSS?

Comment: @Anne [This](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Using_SPSS_and_PASW/Confidence_Intervals) describes how to compute a confidence interval in SPSS. I do not have SPSS so I cannot check it.

Comment: @Chris Thanks! I searched the help but I could not find it. Very clear, thanks. The answer is exactly the same as the answer you got in SAS ie 2.7795 to 5.2205.